# Test Transactional APIs when using loopback memory connector

Tags: node.js, loopback

Am writing tests to check an API endpoint that I need transactions for.

All my tests use the Memory Connector so as not to fill up the db with useless data. However Transactions are not supported by the memory connector.

How should I test the transactional API while using loopback memory connector.

Comment: have you ever found an answer?

Comment: No my friend. I guess the thing to do would be to have a test mysql db and run tests there.